# Where can i find this widget in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

i want to use this widget from eclipse in my GUI.
I've heard that this is built in with xml and comes from eclipse, but I don't know where to find it.
[image: Drop Down Arrow Widget]

Answer (score 0):

It's an `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu` control with the `SWT.BAR` style (see [the code](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.jface/src/org/eclipse/jface/action/MenuManager.java#L204))

Comment: This is not what is used for this tool bar item.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a `ToolItem` in the view tool bar created using an image which is internal to Eclipse ("icons/full/elcl16/view_menu.png" in the "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt" plug-in to be exact).

If you are writing a View Eclipse will generate this automatically if you contribute items to the 'view menu'.